# Extracting number from string in bash script

Tags: bash, awk, sed, aws-cli

I have multiple s3 buckets in AWS whose names are in the following syntax:

1. resource-4511-deployment-1srsi6fjy9uuk
2. web-4533-logbucket-dogx6k0n8967
3. pcnfile6511
4. 5399-bucket-6dehb5uuiwd

I'd like to extract the 4 digit number from each of these names preferably without using multiple if else loops which is the solution I can think of right now. The output should basically be

- 4511
- 4533
- 6511
- 5399

Comment: Did you try `grep`?

Comment: `grep -Po '(?<=-)\d{4}(?=-)'`

Comment: `sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{4}).*/\1/' file`

Answer (score 2):

You can use **parameter expansion**. Prefix and suffix removal return the strings before and after the four digits, you can then use the removal again to remove the prefix and suffix:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for name in resource-4511-deployment-1srsi6fjy9uuk \
            web-4533-logbucket-dogx6k0n8967 \
            pcnfile6511 \
            5399-bucket-6dehb5uuiwd
do
    after=${name#*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}
    before=${name%%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*}
    num=${name#$before}
    num=${num%$after}
    echo $num
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use regex matching here.

I was hoping the pattern would be cleaner, but the data forces this:

```bash
re='(^|[^[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]{4})($|[^[:digit:]])'
```

start of string or a non-digit
followed by 4 digits
followed by end of string or a non-digit

```bash
for name in resource-4511-deployment-1srsi6fjy9uuk \
            web-4533-logbucket-dogx6k0n8967 \
            pcnfile6511 \
            5399-bucket-6dehb5uuiwd
do
    [[ $name =~ $re ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's only one set of 4-digits in each string, one `bash` idea using a regex and the `BASH_REMATCH[]` array:

```
regex='([0-9]{4})'

for string in resource-4511-deployment-1srsi6fjy9uuk web-4533-logbucket-dogx6k0n8967 pcnfile6511 5399-bucket-6dehb5uuiwd
do
    [[ "${string}" =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done
```

This generates:

```
4511
4533
6511
5399
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "pcnfile6511" | grep "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
```

That seems to work, although it only will for four digit numbers.

Also...

```
printf "resource-4511-deployment-1srsi6fjy9uuk" | cut -d'-' -f2
```

That will work when you have delimiters.

For numbers at the end of a line...

```
printf "pcnfile6511" | tail -c 4
```

And for numbers at the beginning...

```
printf "5399-bucket-6dehb5uuiwd" | head -c 4
```